# Upgrading an int column to enum type in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, enums, database-migration

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655820/upgrading-a-varchar-column-to-enum-type-in-postgresql) I was wondering if there as in elegant way to do the same for int values.

More precisely given an Integer column with a fixed number of values (not necessarily contiguous), how would I go about mapping each number to each enum value. And when I say *map* I mean *migrate*

For example:
Lets assume the enum is [as](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-enum.html)

```
CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
```

We would like to map:

```
0 -> 'sad'
1 -> 'ok'
10 -> 'happy'
```

Where, let's say, we have table which contains a column called mood with values {0,1,10} only.

Also, I can't see that the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827122/converting-an-integer-to-enum-in-postgresql) helps me.

I use Postgres 9.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `USING` clause is an expression to tell postgresql how to transform the value.  This is an expression just as you might use in `SELECT`.  So if you need to specify a mapping then you can just use a `CASE` statement.

```
alter table foo 
  alter bar type mood 
  using 
     case bar 
        when 0 then 'sad' 
        when 1 then 'ok' 
        when 10 then 'happy' 
     end :: mood;
```